# How to remove superfluous characters from returned list result by print statement

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a small application connected to a DB.
I can insert data with raw_input and then I have select query to return some results as a report.

this is the code snippet:

```
if user_input == 'Y':
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand, Values)
    cursor.execute(SQLCommand1)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    print 'The total costs until now are '
    print result
```

This is the ouput:

```
The total costs until now are 
[(2061.1, )]
```

I simply need to see only the number, without any special characters. Should I use pprint?

Thanks

Comment: What module are you using for database access?

Comment: The key to removing those characters is to understand where they come from and what they represent.

Comment: I am using pyodbc with SQL Server

Comment: "I simply need to see only the number, without any special characters." --- Then you should _print_ only the number, and not the data structures that contain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `[]` in the output means that the `result` is a list. Inside the list, the `()` means that the single element of the list is a tuple. If you are unfamiliar with lists and tuples, you definitely need to read about them in the official Python tutorial. These are the bread and butter of Python programming.

There are two ways you can get the result you want.

1. Index by row and column position:

   ```
   print result[0][0]
   ```
2. Index by row position and column name:

   ```
   print result[0]['total']
   ```

**Note**

If you know that you will only get a single row from your query, you can also use `fetchone()` instead of `fetchall()`:

```
result = cursor.fetchone()
print result['total']
```

Comment: This is a more complete answer than the fgitw with 2 votes.

Comment: I concur with @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, this answer is superior to mine.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the returned `result` is a list (the `[]`) containing a single tuple (the `()`). So, index into the list and then the tuple to get the value you want:

```
print result[0][0]
```

Comment: yep, this is the one I needed. Thanks, mate!